# Interpolating strings in Javascript - French keyboard

Tags: javascript, string, keyboard

I have a French AZERTY keyboard and I would like to use `` in order to interpolate strings in JS. Yet, I ain't find a way to do this without shifting the keyboard to english.

Is there a way to get `` in a french keyboard ?

Comment: Isn't it on your 7 key? (Is it a French AZERTY keyboard or a Canadian keyboard?)

Comment: I have it on `ctrl+alt+7`

Comment: It is a French AZERTY keyboard and there is an "è" on 7 key

Comment: Thanks @Hearner it's working

Answer (score 1):

You have `è`, `7` and ` on your 7th key 7.

`ctrl+alt+7` is what you want

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot!